# Only 1 CPU Core is used in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, multi-core

I have the following configuration.

Quad Core

Windows Server 2008

IIS 7.5

4GB RAM 32 bit

I have hosted MVC 1 application in this server. But when running this application yields that only 1 CPU Core is used.

Is there is any setting in IIS 7.5 or Windows Server so that all available cores are used/utilised.

Comment: How many simultaneous request are there? If there is only one, then only one CPU will be used for that request. Unless Windows desides to swap it to another CPU, but then only that CPU will be running.

Answer (score 7):

IIS already uses all cores by default.  What you are likely seeing is a single request using a single thread and thus a single core.  This is by design.

If you make a 2nd request to the server, you should see that it hits a new core.  With multiple users you should see even distribution across your cores.

If you need a single request to a single page use all cores then you'll need to specifically design it for that.  That will require starting multiple threads to handle the single request.  That's uncommon for IIS type load though that usually assumes dozens, hundreds or thousands of users rather than a single user gaining 100% of the resources of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the processor affinity (via Task Manager) for process: w3wp.exe.

Are you asking what you can do so that at code runtime, more than one core is utilised?

Answer (score 0):

How did you test that?

Seriously.

- If you haveonly one session / user, access is serial under one session cookie (asp.net serializeds all processing).
- TO really see you use only one core you need to get over 25% cpu usage. Depending how bad a programmer you are and how trivial your pages are this may require between 2 users at the same time and possibly 2000.... because pages should normally process FAST.

So,

how did you test that? WHat makes you come to this conclusion?